# Remove time in date format in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I using:

```
s = "20200113"
final = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')
```

I need convert a number in date format (2020-01-13)
but when I print final:

```
2020-01-13 00:00:00
```

Tried datetime.date(s, '%Y%m%d') but It's returns a error:

```
an integer is required (got type str)
```

Is there any command to get only date without hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strftime` to convert back in the format you need :

```
import datetime
s = "20200113"

temp = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')
# 2020-01-13 00:00:00

final = temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(final)
# 2020-01-13
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a `datetime` object just use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```py
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()  # Some datetime object.
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

which gives

```
2020-02-20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.date()` on `datetime` objects to 'remove' the time.

```py
my_time_str = str(final.date())
```

will give you the wanted result

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datetime.date(year, month, day)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date).  Slice your string and convert to integers to get the year, month and day.  Now it is a `datetime.date` object, you can use it for other things.  Here, however, we use `.strftime` to convert it back to text in your desired format.

```
s = "20200113"
year = int(s[:4])  # 2020
month = int(s[4:6])  # 1
day = int(s[6:8])  # 13
>>> datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2020-01-13'
```

You can also convert directly via strings.

```
>>> f'{s[:4]}-{s[4:6]}-{s[6:8]}'
'2020-01-13'
```